# Loss of context in multiple blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a super class that will be extended. The super class will call a method that has to be implemented by the child class. The thing is, that method is called sometimes 3 blocks deep. In those blocks, I also refer to `attributes` of the class.

But, I get an error saying that there is no variable or method, and it's because the methods and variables are assumed to be from the block class.

This is how it looks like:

```
class SuperClass
  attr_accessor :model

  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def resources
    s = Tire.search(get_index) do
      query do
        boolean do
          must { term :model_id, model.id } #attr_accessor fails

          must { all }

          search_scope(self) #search_scope fails
        end
      end

      sort do
        sort_scope(self) #sort_scope fails
      end
    end

    s.results
  end
end

class SubClass < SuperClass
  attr_accessor :params

  def initialize(model, params)
    @params = params
    super(model)
  end

  def search_scope(boolean_query)
    boolean_query.must { term field: params[:feild] }
    #...
  end

  def sort_scope(sort_query)
    sort_query.by :field, params[:sort_dir]
    #...
  end
end

search = SubClass.new(model, {})
results = search.resources # undefined method error as explained below
```

What I'm trying to achieve is calling the method `search_scope` and `sort_scope` (Implemented in child classes) that will set also set a few search and sort parameters. But I get `undefined method 'search_scope' for #<Tire::Search::BooleanQuery:0x00000004fc9820>`. As you can see, it's trying to call `search_scope` on the class of the block context. Same with the `attr_accessor :model`.

I know I can remedy this by doing

```
def resources
  instance = self
  # ...
end
```

And then calling `instance.model` and `instance.search_scope`, but this means my child classes have to define the instance in their own `search_scope` and `sort_scope` methods too.

I was wondering whether there is a better way to solving this?

Comment: If a concrete example of a child class is needed, please let me know.

Comment: it would be great if you could provide a small abstract self-executable example, toghether with the execution code and the error log (something like `class SuperClass ... end; class SubClass ... end; Subclass.new.... bang! Error: ...` This half-completed code is not error-focused and causes confusion IMHO

Comment: @mdesantis Good point added a concrete example